# How to select a row from any hstore values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I've a table `Content` in a PostgreSQL (9.5) database, which contains the column `title`. The `title` column is a `hstore`. It's a `hstore`, because the `title` is translated to different languages. For example:

```
example=# SELECT * FROM contents;
 id |                    title                    |                    content                     |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+---------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | "de"=>"Beispielseite", "en"=>"Example page" | "de"=>"Beispielinhalt", "en"=>"Example conten" | 2016-07-17 09:20:23.159248 | 2016-07-17 09:20:23.159248
    (1 row)
```

My question is, how can I select the `content` which `title` contains `Example page`?

```
SELECT * FROM contents WHERE title = 'Example page';
```

This query unfortunately doesn't work.

```
example=# SELECT * FROM contents WHERE title = 'Example page';
ERROR:  Syntax error near 'p' at position 8
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM contents WHERE title = 'Example page';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `avals()` function returns an array of all values in a `hstore` column. You can then match your value using `any` against that array:

```
select *
from contents 
where 'Example page' = any(avals(title))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like in where clause

```
SELECT * FROM contents WHERE title like '%Example page%';
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: `title` is a `hstore` column. You can't use `LIKE` on a `hstore`

Comment: Is it can be casting to varchar datatype?

Comment: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: hstore ~~ unknown`